# debian howto disable gpg-agent-browser.socket

Tags: debian, gpg, gpg-agent

On server there is no browser nore gui, so is it possible to disable the `gpg-agent-browser.socket` ?

On debian 10.13 I can see those files:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent.service
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent-ssh.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gpg-agent.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gpg-agent-ssh.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gpg-agent-extra.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/gpg-agent-browser.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent-extra.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/user/gpg-agent-browser.socket
```

I could not find the answer on Internet, do you have an idea on howto disable the gpg-agent-browser stuff ?

Thanks & cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a user service, so it’s only active in user sessions started by systemd. On a server, it’s likely you don’t have any most of the time.

If you do want to disable it, you need to do so for each user:

```
systemctl --user disable gpg-agent-browser.socket
```